# What is happening in the scene with Coldmoon and the geisha?

Tags: i-am-a-cat, japanese-language, natsume-soseki

In chapter two of *I Am a Cat*, we see this scene:

> As we turned at Hotan’s corner another geisha appeared. She was slim, well-shaped and her shoulders were most beautifully sloped. The way she wore her mauve kimono gave her a genuine elegance. “Sorry about last night, Gen-chan—I was so busy. . .” She laughed and one glimpsed white teeth. Her voice was so harsh, as harsh as that of a roving crow, that her otherwise fine appearance diminished in enchantment. So much so that I didn’t even bother to turn around to see what sort of person this Gen-chan was, but sauntered on toward Onarimachi with my hands tucked inside the breast-fold of my kimono. Coldmoon, however, seemed to have become a trifle fidgety.
>   <sub>*I Am a Cat*, chapter 2</sub>

I'm a little confused as to what is supposed to be happening in this scene. What was she busy with? What does the rough voice imply? Why does Coldmoon become fidgety?